# Getting Session value to Javascript

Tags: javascript, php

I want to use `$_SESSION['total']` in javascript so I can use it in a function.

***What I have tried:***

`var total = '<%= Session["total"]%>';` Prints: `<%= Session["total"]%>`

`var total = <?php $_SESSION['total']; ?>;` Prints `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <`

`var total = "<?php $_SESSION[\'total\']; ?>";` Prints `<?php $_SESSION[\'total\']; ?>`

Is there a way of getting the session value and use it in javascript?

***EDIT:***
Ok, if the you are trying this in an external javascript, it doesn't work, it work when you write the script in the php, well for me.

Comment: The problems you're having indicate that the page isn't being executed by PHP. Does it have a `.php` extension? Are you accessing it from a webserver?

Comment: @Barmar the javascript is an external javascript

Comment: You need to put it in a `.php` file so that the server will process it with PHP. Or configure the webserver so that it processes `.js` files with PHP.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The second one should be fine, but you must also put echo before the session:

```
var total = <?php echo $_SESSION["total"]; ?>;
```

Comment: His `<?php` is getting into the Javascript. That means it's not being processed by PHP.

Comment: When the complete page gets rendered in the server side, php runtime translates `<?php echo $_SESSION["total"]; ?>` into actual session value. That's the concept behind it. so, the javascript variable `total` will have the actual value getting set into it

Comment: @Keerthivasan The problem he's having is that the file isn't being rendered by PHP. He apparently tried putting PHP code inside a `.js` file.